# Problems with a wms layer in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, wms

I'm trying to add a layer into an `Openlayers 3` map. This one is which I want to insert:

```
new ol.layer.Image({ name: 'cartografia', style: 'cartografia', visible: true, source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({ url: 'http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?', params: { 'LAYERS': '1', 'STYLES': 'default' }, serverType: 'geoserver' }) })
```

When I go to the [webpage](http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities) I can see the XML, but I'm not able to insert the layer

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this WMS and everything seems fine. I did notice however that no error was been thrown if I had my projection set to 3857. This is not supported by this WMS for the layer you mentioned. Make sure that you are using a supported projection for the desired layer on the WMS.

```
<Name>1</Name>
<Title>Itzalak / Sombras MDT LIDAR 2012 5000</Title>
<Abstract>Itzalak / Sombras MDT LIDAR 2012 5000</Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:23030</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:25830</CRS>
```

You can see a example of a map uisng 4326. In the link below,

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/epsg-4326.html

I added the layer using the following code to a map using EPSG: 4326,

```
var test = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/U11_AGS_WMS_Cartografia/MapServer/WMSServer',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': '1'
        }
    })
})
```

And I got the following result over Spain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is "serverType: 'geoserver'", because the WMS is not hosted by GeoServer, but ESRI ArcGIS Server.

If You leave the serverType undefined and set projection: 'EPSG:4326' in the View Options, Your code will work.